# The intersection of finite number of convex hulls is a convex hull.

Tags: geometry, convex-hulls

What is the easiest way to prove that the intersection of finite number of convex hulls is a convex hull?

It seems to be an easy statement to prove, but still I can not get even the idea of proving. So, I would be grateful even for an idea behind the prove.

**Edit:** Information pulled from comments: We are talking about in the plane, and a "convex hull" here is a convex polygon - that is, the convex hull of a finite set of points.

Comment: The intersection of any collection of convex sets is convex, and every convex set is the convex hull of itself.

Comment: Yeah, this question is only interesting if by "convex hull" you mean "convex hull of a finite set."

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, ok. I feel it intuitively. And now I want to prove it. It is the reason I asked it here.

Comment: To show the first half of that (that the intersection of a collection of convex sets is convex), consider any two points in the intersection. By definition, they're in each set in the collection, and since those sets are convex then the line between them is in each set in the collection, so..

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, why is not it interesting for an infinite number of convex hulls?

Comment: That's not what I wrote. @ЯрикТроф I said a convex hull of a finite set of points. As noted above, a set is a convex hull if and only if it is convex, so it is only proving that intersections of convex sets are convex.

Comment: Thomas's comment is that 'the intersection of a finite number of convex hulls of a finite set of points is also the convex hull of a finite set of points' is more interesting. It's also true, but you need a little bit of linear programming to show it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, will convex hull of an infinite set take up the whole universal set?

Comment: Is it enough to say as @StevenStadnicki suggested? We have convex hulls intersection. Let us consider two points from the intersection. They belong to all convex hulls. We can draw a line between them. Hence, the resulting set is convex.

Comment: That shows that the resulting set is convex (which may be all you want - the question is a bit confusing as it stands) but that isn't enough to show that it's the convex hull of a finite set of points.

Comment: @ЯрикТроф Sure, but that proof applies to any number of convex sets, including infinitely many, so I'm still guessing that your definition of convex hull is not the most general one. What definition of convex hull are you using?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, there are three definition that I am using. First one is about convex polygon with the smallest perimeter, second one is about intersection of all convex hulls that include the set and the last one is about a line segment which can connect any two points in the set.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the attention!

Comment: Also, are you talking only in two dimension, or more generally $n$-dimension?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I am talking only about two dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** In the plane, a set $X$ is the convex hull of a finite set of points if and only if $X$ is convex and it is either a single point, a line segment, or can be written as the union of a finite number of triangles (where a triangle includes its boundary and interior.)

The we need to prove:

1. The intersection of two convex sets is convex.
2. The intersection of two triangles is a convex hull (where an empty set is considered the convex hull on an empty set.)
3. The intersection of a line segment and a triangle is either a point, a line segment, or empty.
4. The intersection of a line segment and a line segment is either a point, a line segment, or empty.

From this, you get that if $X$ and $Y$ are both convex hulls of finite sets, then $X\cap Y$ is a convex hull of a finite set.

Then you get your full result by induction.

Each of these parts are relatively easy to show, with (2) requiring the most details.

---

There are two possible definitions of "convex hull" here. There is a "usual definition," but there are reasons in this question to think that your question is asking about another definition.

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. The the "convex hull of $X$" is the smallest convex set that contains $X$. In particular, this can be written as the set of points:

$$H(X)=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid x=t_1x_1+t_2x_2+\cdots+t_nx_n,\,x_i\in X,\,t_i\geq 0, \sum t_i=1\right\}$$

Now, one might define "a convex hull" to be any $H(X)$, but (1) that's uniteresting, because then "a convex hull" is the same as a convex set - if $Y$ is a convex set, then $H(Y)=Y$. Also, with this definition of "convex hull," you don't need the "finite" part of your question.

On the other hand, one might define "a convex hull" as any $H(X)$ where $X$ is finite. In that definition, the nature of $H(X)$ is that it's boundaries are all 'flat.' But it is also tricky to prove that a finite intersection of such hulls is still such a hull.

From your comment above, particularly the reference to polygons, it does seem like you mean this second type: $H(X)$ for some finite set $X$.